# OTRS Complete Ticket Information with linked Config Item

Tags: java, perl, soap, otrs

I have a requirement to get complete ticket information along with the linked config item (for example, computer, hardware, network etc.) using SOAP or a restful API call.

I have created a SOAP webservice which is giving me the below output

```
 1. Type:Unclassified
 2. SLAID:
 3. EscalationResponseTime:0
 4. Title:test mail
 5. Queue:Postmaster
 6. TicketID:3
 7. Owner:XXXX.johnson@XXXXXXXXX.com
 8. State:open
 9. Priority:3 normal
 10. CreateTimeUnix:1450425201
 11. StateID:4
 12. Responsible:root@localhost
 13. CustomerID:XXXXXX.johnson@XXXXXXXXX.com
 14. UnlockTimeout:1450425202
 15. PriorityID:3
 16. EscalationUpdateTime:0
 17. OwnerID:2
 18. UntilTime:0
 19. EscalationTime:0
 20. CreateBy:2
 21. LockID:1
 22. Lock:unlock
 23. ArchiveFlag:n
 24. RealTillTimeNotUsed:0
 25. ChangeBy:2
 26. ServiceID:
 27. Created:2015-12-18 13:23:21
 28. QueueID:1
 29. CustomerUserID:XXXXXXX.johnson@XXXXXXX.com
 30. Age:949546
 31. GroupID:1
 32. TicketNumber:2015121854000021
 33. TypeID:1
 34. StateType:open
 35. ResponsibleID:1
 36. EscalationSolutionTime:0
 37. Changed:2015-12-18 13:23:29
```

but here I am not getting the linked config item (computer) information. If I open the `AgentTicketZoom` page in a browser it's showing.

[image: Find image]

Now I want to get this information (config item number, name, deployed state, linked as, device, type, IP,address etc.) along with it.

Below is my `GenericTicketConnectorSOAP.yml` webservice I imported in admin console for SOAP Calls

```
---
Debugger:
  DebugThreshold: debug
  TestMode: 0
Description: Ticket Connector SOAP Sample
FrameworkVersion: 4.x git
Provider:
  Operation:
    SessionCreate:
      Description: Creates a Session
      MappingInbound: {}
      MappingOutbound: {}
      Type: Session::SessionCreate
    TicketCreate:
      Description: Creates a Ticket
      MappingInbound: {}
      MappingOutbound: {}
      Type: Ticket::TicketCreate
    TicketUpdate:
      Description: Updates a Ticket
      MappingInbound: {}
      MappingOutbound: {}
      Type: Ticket::TicketUpdate
    TicketGet:
      Description: Retrieve Ticket data
      MappingInbound: {}
      MappingOutbound: {}
      Type: Ticket::TicketGet
    TicketSearch:
      Description: Search for Tickets
      MappingInbound: {}
      MappingOutbound: {}
      Type: Ticket::TicketSearch
  Transport:
    Config:
      MaxLength: 100000000
      NameSpace: http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/
    Type: HTTP::SOAP
RemoteSystem: ''
Requester:
  Transport:
    Type: ''
```

Can some one help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand, that you have to define the method, that can retrieve the links from the ticket in your webservice config.

To give you the hint, you should add a new controller in your wsdl / yml file, which will be the LinkObject and its method LinkList ( Kernel::System::LinkObject )

```
 my $LinkList = $LinkObject->LinkList(
    Object    => 'Ticket',
    Key       => '321',
    Object2   => 'FAQ',         # (optional)
    State     => 'Valid',
    Type      => 'ParentChild', # (optional)
    Direction => 'Target',      # (optional) default Both (Source|Target|Both)
    UserID    => 1,
);
```

And afterwards use this method to retrieve all links of a ticket